# How to remove an element from a nested list?

Tags: python, list

if I have a nested list such as:

```
m=[[34,345,232],[23,343,342]]
```

if I write `m.remove(345)` it gives an error message saying the element is not in the list.

I want to know how to remove an element from the nested list, easily.

Comment: dupe. exactly the same question was asked just a few days ago.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Please post the link in your comment pointing to that question.

Comment: yes please give the link of the duplicate question,i may get few suggestion from that too

Comment: possible duplicate of [using remove on nested lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021167/using-remove-on-nested-lists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no shortcut for this.  You have to remove the value from every nested list in the container list:

```
for L in m:
    try:
        L.remove(345)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

If you want similiar behavior like `list.remove`, use something like the following:

```
def remove_nested(L, x):
    for S in L:
        try:
            S.remove(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            break  # Value was found and removed
    else:
        raise ValueError("remove_nested(L, x): x not in nested list")
```

Answer (score 9):

```
In [5]: m=[[34,345,232],[23,343,342]]

In [7]: [[ subelt for subelt in elt if subelt != 345 ] for elt in m] 
Out[7]: [[34, 232], [23, 343, 342]]
```

Note that `remove(345)` only removes the first occurrance of of 345 (if it exists). The above code removes all occurrances of 345.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one nested level this could help

```
def nested_remove(L, x):
    if x in L:
        L.remove(x)
    else:
        for element in L:
            if type(element) is list:
                nested_remove(element, x)

>>> m=[[34,345,232],[23,343,342]]
>>> nested_remove(m, 345)
>>> m
[[34, 232], [23, 343, 342]]

>>> m=[[34,[345,56,78],232],[23,343,342]]
>>> nested_remove(m, 345)
>>> m
[[34, [56, 78], 232], [23, 343, 342]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove 345 by using this code.

```py
m[0].remove(345)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i=0
for item in nodes:
    for itm in item:
        m=database_index[itm]
        print m
        if m[1]=='text0526' or m[1]=='text0194' or m[1]=='phone0526' or m[1]=='phone0194':
            nodes[i].remove(itm)
    i+=1
```

this i how i solved my problem by using a variable i to save the above level of the nested list.

Comment: Instead of using an explicit variable `i`, you could also use the `enumerate()` wrapper: `for i, item in enumerate(nodes):`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove **only by indexes** you can use this method

```py
m[0].pop(1)
```

by this you can specify only the index.
This is helpful *if you know only the position* you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete by using delete:-  `del m[1][1]`
or  by using below code

```
for i in m:
    for j in i:
        if j==345:
            i.remove(j)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut of doing this is using del command:

```
del list[element] element[nested element] 

del [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same item (i.e. 345) in more places to remove from the nested list, you can try:

```
for x in m:
    for index in range(len(x) -1, -1, -1):
        if x[index] == 345:
            del x[index]
    print(x)
```

or

```
for x in m:
    for z in x:
        if z != 345:
            print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of the element then you can use 'del' function.

```
m=[[34,345,232],[23,343,342]]
del m[0][1]
```