# How to remove a string of a certain length from a nested list?

Tags: string, python-3.x, nested, nested-lists

I have a nested list of strings, **corpus** consisting of lists of different lengths. I want to keep only strings whose lengths are greater than 2.

From the similar question in [how to remove an element from a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055358/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-nested-list) I tried all the answers that allowed me to indicate the condition length >2.

## Code

```
corpus = list(r_corpus('teeny.txt'))
print('initial corpus here ',corpus)

#Current attempt
[[ subelt for subelt in elt if len(subelt) >2 ] for elt in corpus] 

#previous attempt 1
##for thing in corpus:
##    [y for y in thing if len(y)>2]

#previous attempt 2
##for sentence in corpus:
##    sentence = [x for x in sentence if len(x) > 2 ]

print('\n\n corpus here without any string of length 2 or smaller',corpus)
```

This is the output of the current attempt , which is the same for the two previous attempts.

initial **corpus** here

```
[['extracting', 'opinions'],
['soo', 'min', 'kim', 'and'],
['abstract'],
['this', 'paper', 'presents', 'method', 'for', 'identifying', 'an'], 
['this', 'section', 'reviews', 'previous', 'works', 'in'], 
['subjectivity', 'detection', 'is'], 
['work', 'is', 'similar', 'to', 'ours', 'but', 'different']]
```

**corpus** with any string of length 2 or smaller

```
[['extracting', 'opinions'],
['soo', 'min', 'kim', 'and'], 
['abstract'], 
['this', 'paper', 'presents', 'method', 'for', 'identifying', 'an'], 
['this', 'section', 'reviews', 'previous', 'works', 'in'], 
['subjectivity', 'detection', 'is'], 
['work', 'is', 'similar', 'to', 'ours', 'but', 'different']]
```

## What I need

The fastest possible way to have the second version of the corpus without any strings of length 2 or smaller:

**corpus** without any string of length 2 or smaller

```
[['extracting', 'opinions'], 
['soo', 'min', 'kim', 'and'], 
['abstract'], 
['this', 'paper', 'presents', 'method', 'for', 'identifying'], 
['this', 'section', 'reviews', 'previous', 'works'],
['subjectivity', 'detection'],
['work','similar','ours', 'but', 'different']]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it just 2D list of strings?iterate by nested for and check for length, if length is lower than 2, del item.

Comment: Thanks, this way it works, but wouldn't be a faster way? The real corpus has millions of words.
for sentence in corpus:
    for x in sentence:
        if len(x) <= 2:
            sentence.remove(x)

Comment: **@Vera**, use **map()**, **filter()**, **lambda function**, **list comprehension** to solve. It doesn't use **for** and **if** keywords and your code will look more professional.

Answer (score 0):

**@Vera**, you can try the below code. It uses concepts like **list comprehension**, **lambda function**, **map()**, **filter** etc.

> Use of **list comprehension**, **lambda function**, **map()**, **filter()**, **reduce()** etc. is a Pythonic way to solve problems in easier, efficient and concise way.
>
> You can check [List comprehension](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html) and [map(), filter(), reduce(), lambda function](https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php) etc. to have a look at the given examples related to these concepts with explanation.

```
import json

corpus = [['extracting', 'opinions'],
['soo', 'min', 'kim', 'and'],
['abstract'],
['this', 'paper', 'presents', 'method', 'for', 'identifying', 'an'], 
['this', 'section', 'reviews', 'previous', 'works', 'in'], 
['subjectivity', 'detection', 'is'], 
['work', 'is', 'similar', 'to', 'ours', 'but', 'different']]

new_corpus = list( map(lambda words: list(filter(lambda word: len(word)> 2, words)), corpus))

# Pretty printing list of lists of words of length > 2
print(json.dumps(new_corpus, indent=2))

"""
[
  [
    "extracting",
    "opinions"
  ],
  [
    "soo",
    "min",
    "kim",
    "and"
  ],
  [
    "abstract"
  ],
  [
    "this",
    "paper",
    "presents",
    "method",
    "for",
    "identifying"
  ],
 [
    "this",
    "section",
    "reviews",
    "previous",
    "works"
  ],
  [
    "subjectivity",
    "detection"
  ],
  [
    "work",
    "similar",
    "ours",
    "but",
    "different"
  ]
]
"""
```

Comment: Why is `lambda` + `map` + `filter` faster than a list comprehension? Have you timed performance to check it actually is faster?

Comment: **@jpp**, yea I checked the times. `[[ subelt for subelt in elt if len(subelt) >2 ] for elt in corpus]` is fastest among other solutions and it should be because the use of **map()**, **filter()**, **lambda functions** etc. increases little amount of time. As I tested, it took 3 more seconds for 1 million times of corpus i.e. `corpus * 1000000`.

Comment: Absolutely, +1, it is indeed faster. This is what I needed. Thanks!- this can be closed, btw.