# Remove all nan from nested list

Tags: python

I'm attempting to remove all nan list items from a nested list

```
l1= 
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, nan],
 ['red', 'orange', 'blue', nan, nan, nan]]
```

I've tried the following

```
cleanedList = [x for x in l1 if str(x) != 'nan']
```

However, this returns the same output

Comment: hi, perhaps filter the nested list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055358/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-nested-list

Comment: You're comparing `nan` (presumably from `numpy`?) with `'nan'` which is a string, so the two will never match and nothing gets filtered out.

Comment: without list comprehension:

l1= [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, nan],
 ['red', 'orange', 'blue', nan, nan, nan]]

cleanedList = []
for oldList in l1:
    newList = []
    for val in oldList:
        if val is not nan:
            newList.append(val)
    cleanedList.append(newList)
print(cleanedList)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nan` is not equal to itself (this goes for `float('nan')` as well as `np.nan`). So, we can use `filter()`, removing elements which are not equal to itself.

```py
l1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 
      [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, nan], 
      ['red', 'orange', 'blue', nan, nan, nan]]

result = [list(filter(lambda x: x == x, inner_list)) for inner_list in l1]

print(result)
```