# Remove an element of a list that is inside another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new to Python and programming in general. I have searched through the forum but i haven't found an answer. Sorry in advance if it's already in the forum...

**So, let's say I have a this list:**

```
list = [  ["Dog", "Cat"] ,  ["12", "14"]  ]
```

**How can i remove the list ["Dog", "Cat"] ?**

I have tried to code this (but it does nothing):

```
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    for y in range(0,len(list[i])):
        if list[i] == item:   
            list.remove(item)
```

#item is a input where the user specify which list wants to remove by typing one word of the list. So if the user input is: item = Dog it should remove the list `["Dog", "Cat"]` and leave `list = [  ["12", "14"]  ]`

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an element from a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055358/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a nice logic but you need make few mistake in logic of that you are not seeing elements of list's sub-list and trying to remove element in not specified properly try this code

```
list = [  ["Dog", "Cat"] ,  ["12", "14"]  ]

item='Cat'
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    for y in range(0,len(list[i])):
        if list[i][y] == item:
            list[i].remove(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

First never name a list `list`, that's the method to build a list, don't redefine it.

Then instead of `values.remove(item)` you'd like to do `values.remove(values[i])`, BUT removing parts of a list whild iterating on it isn't a good idea, because you'll have

- `i=0` => remove the `["Dog", "Cat"]` part, the list has now 1 value
- `i=1` => there is nothing left at position 1, crash

---

The best ideas are : keep what you want instead of removing it

- with a loop

  ```
  values = [["Dog", "Cat"], ["12", "14"]]
  item = "Dog"
  result = []
  for sublist in values:
      if item not in sublist:
          result.append(sublist)
  print(result)
  ```
- with a list comprehension

  ```
  result = [sublist for sublist in values if item not in sublist]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and this one worked for me.

`list = [sublist for sublist in list if user_input.lower() not in sublist]`